# MVC3 architecture about Sales Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, architecture

I'm currently on the task of developing a Sales/CRM application on MVC3.
Since lots of opperations revolve around a given order (that can ve saved and later used) I was wondering some questions.

1. I want tabs for a quote for the customer and an internal order view. How can i handle the behaviour so when a client opens a given order he/she can stay within the same order?
2. The Order has information to generate various other Excel documents (like supplier invoices and shipping orders) I need to implement a way to "fill up" those forms. The forms are in Excel format, is there any way to "fill" an excel from a C# application and then generate the file?

Thank you.

Comment: For future reference: If you have two separate questions as you currently do, you should ask two separate questions. Don't place them both in one question.

Comment: roger that, I'm new to actually making questions in stackO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question sounds like a problem of persistence. You can use sessions to persist data across pages. For example, if you have some sort of `Order` class you can create a new `Order` when the customer does something that requires it:

```
\\ first use:
var order = new Order();
order.Details = "Blah blah blah";
Session["Order"] = order;
```

Later on, you can obtain it using the same mechanism:

```
\\ You should check if this exists first
var order = (Order) Session["Order"];
order.SomethingUseful();
```

Personally, I write some wrappers around the `Session` to make it strongly typed and so I can unit test it properly. Something along the lines of:

```
interface ISessionWrapper
{
    Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

Then I can implement it as:

```
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    {
        get { return (Session["Order"] ?? Session["Order"] = new Order()); }
        set { Session["Order"] = value; }
    }
```

in some concrete class. It becomes easy to mock and unit test as well.

Answer (score 0):

The first question is not clear to me so I will answer only the second one

for generating excel from your model you can use [openXml SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx). With this dll you can generate word or excel from scratch without the need to install office on the server (with interop you had to do that)

hope it helps

Comment: AWESOME, seems what I need tot do. Either way Office is already on the server, my need is to generate documents from VERY specific spreadsheet templates, since lots of them are custom invoices from customers or government formats, so you think I can use this SDK for that purpose?

Comment: Yes. I used it just for that in a project. In case of word I open a document, replace some bookmarks and send the new document to client. In case of excel I open an excel change/set some cells values and recalculate some formulas.